# How can I open a link in a new window with `target="_blank"`?

Tags: html

How can I add in `target="_blank"` to open the link in a new window?

Here is my current code:

```
<a id="go" href="<?php echo site_url('external/url/'.$deal->id);?>">
```

Comment: given your response to the answer below that merely added the target attribute to the markup, i'll vote for Not A Real Question.

Comment: Please do not use `target` at all. Let users choose if they want a new tab/window or not!

Comment: *(related)* [To target blank or not to target blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906898/to-target-blank-or-not-to-target-blank-that-is-the-question)

Comment: *(suggested reading)* http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H83.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a id="go" target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url('external/url/'.$deal->id);?>">
```